# WSL unable to access network

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I had WSL 1 working fine, but when I updated to WSL 2, I now have no network access.  in the ubuntu 20.04 distro, I can ping my own ip (which shows up with "ip a") but I can't ping (or access at all) yahoo.com or anything else the way I was able to in WSL 1.

Is there a setting I can change to enable external network access for WSL2?

Comment: Please post the contents of your `/etc/wsl.conf ` and `/etc/resolv.conf` files

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that when using wsl1, my linux has the same network interfaces as my host windows, so it's like it's the host ip itself, eth0, wifi0. When switch to wsl2 it tries tu use hyper-v virtual interface only. It's annoying, but it's what it's no the same. I don't know how to add manually, but maybe whit this type somebody can point us at the right direction.
In the meantime, install your distro, use 1 to get internet access and update, install, etc, then, convert to 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these commands:

```
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
sudo bash -c 'echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf'
sudo bash -c 'echo "[network]" > /etc/wsl.conf'
sudo bash -c 'echo "generateResolvConf = false" >> /etc/wsl.conf'
sudo chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
```

This probably will repair the problems with network in your distro, by default WSL configs the resolv.conf with a different *nameserver*, doing this we're setting the nameserver to the Google DNS.

After doing these configurations, in the Windows PowerShell you can use these command:

```
wsl --list
wsl --shutdown your_distro
```

Doing this you're rebooting your distro, so you can access again your distro and check if the network is okay, try using `ping` or doing something like `sudo apt update`.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZZnV.png)